# jQuery script fails executing for some of the users

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

I am using a custom form to submit data to Google Spreadsheets. When user attempts to submit the form, it is validated (with jQuery) and if the validation is passed, the main input field is being modified with jQuery and then the submission continues.

The user inputs a URL and during submission the script cuts off unnecessary parts of the link and adds IP (that is also gathered with jQ) of the user to it. After the modification is completed, the form continues submission and in result, only the modified data is being sent to Google Spreadsheet.

It works pretty well with 99% of submissions but there are several users whose browsers do not execute the script properly; i.e.: the URL they input is not being modified during the submission and thus, wrong data (unmodified) is sent to the Spreadsheet. I am not completely sure, but the problem may be caused by Firefox (but I am not 100% sure that all the faulty submission come from Firefox, if you want I could research and confirm whether it is only Firefox's issue). I have asked some of them (users, whose browsers seem not to execute script) about addons/if they had turned JS off but they say they did not do anything special with their browsers.

I am posting whole js file below so you could check whether I did some errors that could cause problems. Also, the script is running here ([link](http://fppp.tk)), you can inspect the code to see what other jQuery stuff I use.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //Tabbiing page is being initialised, doesn't really matter, I think
    $.ionTabs("#fppp_taby");

    //Script that checks whether user has been redirected back after submission, that's not the main problematic part yet
    if (window.location.search != 0) {
        var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
        ideo = query.split("=")[1];
        if (isNaN(ideo) || (ideo.length < 3) || (ideo.length > 10)) {
            $("form").html("Wystąpił błąd podczas wysyłania Twojego zgłoszenia. Powiadom mnie o tym poprzez prywatną wiadomość podając również obecną godzinę za pomocą <a class='uline' href='http://www.erepublik.com/pl/main/messages-compose/2417512'>tego linka</a>.");
        } else {
            $("form").html("Dziękujemy za zgłoszenie!<br /><br />Możesz teraz przeczytać któryś z artykułów epolskiej prasy - lista wartch uwagi znajduje się po lewej stronie!");
            var poZglosz = "Dziękujemy za zgłoszenie!<br />Spodziewaj się chlebków i broni od któregoś z tych graczy: Kijek93, twatwaratwa, Gregoric bądź Zawa99";
            $("#poZglos").html(poZglosz);
            $("#poZglos").removeClass();
        }
    } else {
        var query = 0;
    }

    //Some simple stuff
    $("#wlaczirc").click(function() {
        $(this).hide();
        $("#irc").html("<iframe src='http://webchat.quakenet.org/?channels=fppp&amp;uio=OT10cnVlJjExPTM0OQ1f'></iframe>");
        $("#irc").show("slow");
        $("#info_irc").show("slow");
    });

    //Some data
    infoPodkr = "Wklej tutaj prawidłowy link do twojego profilu!";
    inputLink = $("#ffpolelinku");

    //Resetting validation info in input
    $(inputLink).focus(function() {
        if ($(this).hasClass("podkresl") || $(this).val() == infoPodkr) {
            $(this).val("");
            $(this).removeClass("podkresl");
        }
    });


    //Gathering ip
    $.getJSON("http://jsonip.com/",
            function(data) {
                ip = data.ip;
            });


    //MAIN PART (executed when user pressses 'submit')
    $("form").submit(function() {

        //Form is being hidden (display:none class is being added)
        $('aside').addClass("hidden");

        //Check whether input is empty or contains error message (infoPodkr = error message vlaue), if yes, add class 'podkresl'
        if (($(inputLink).val() == "") || ($(inputLink).val() == infoPodkr)) {
            $(inputLink).addClass("podkresl");
            $(inputLink).val(infoPodkr);
        } else {
            $(inputLink).removeClass("podkresl");
        }

        //Tesing whether user added proper link, if not, 'podkresl' is added
        //if (!/\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[\-A-Za-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[\-A-Za-z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]/.test(inputLink.val())){
        if (!/http\:\/\/www\.erepublik\.com\/[a-z]{2}\/citizen\/profile\/\d{5,}$/i.test(inputLink.val())) {
            $(inputLink).addClass("podkresl");
            $(inputLink).val(infoPodkr);
        }

        //Split link, and get the last part of it ('wycId'), check if it's numeral, if not - add 'podkresl' class
        podzielony = $(inputLink).val().split('/');
        wycId = podzielony.pop();


        if (isNaN(wycId)) {
            $(inputLink).addClass("podkresl");
            $(inputLink).val(infoPodkr);
        }

        //Check whether the input class 'podkresl' class (= something was wrong in some of the steps above). If yes, remove the 'hidden' class from 'aside' which holds the form and show it to the user. If there were no errors, add the IP to the 'wycId' and additional "-n" to the end of the value and put it into input. Then, submit form.
        if ($(inputLink).hasClass("podkresl")) {
            $('aside').removeClass();
            return false;
        } else {
            if (ip !== '') {
                $(inputLink).val(wycId + "-" + ip + "-n");
            } else {
                $(inputLink).val(wycId + "-0-n");
            }
        }

        return true;
    });
});
```

Comment: What if the form is submitted before the HTTP request to jsonip.com has completed?

Comment: That could be the possible issue but I thought that there's no way for a user to submit the form faster than the jsonip call is completed - it is being called at the very moment the user enters the website. Also, at the very last step the IP is being checked whether it is empty [[ if (ip !== ''){... ]]

Comment: Okay, I have added $ip = 0; before the external call is to be executed - just to check whether it didn't cause the problem and it seems that it did... that surprised me. I will try to reach the IP of the users in some other way (probably locally). If the problem will be still occur, I will answer again. Thanks for the suggestion.